# Fastest way to convert a float to int in C++

Tags: c++, performance, type-conversion

What is the fastest and most efficient way to convert a float to an integer in c++ (rounding toward zero)? is it

```
long ftoint(float x)
{
    unsigned int e = (0x7F + 31) - ((* (unsigned int*) &x & 0x7F800000) >> 23);
    unsigned int m = 0x80000000 | (* (unsigned int*) &x << 8);
    return int((m >> e) & -(e < 32));
}
```

?

Comment: `int y = x;` ??

Comment: Beside not compiling, the `ftoint` routine also has undefined behavior.

Comment: I honestly dont understand what problem you are trying to solve. The `?` was serious, and I had to double it just to fit the minimum char count ;)

Comment: @TedKleinBergman [No, it doesn't have to be explicit cast](https://wandbox.org/permlink/COCadu717EPQK4W3).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen That's weird... Almost certain it used to be a over-restrictive problem

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number clang encodes your `int y = x;` as a single instruction: `vcvttss2si eax, xmm0`. That seems pretty fast.

Comment: @Random Why do you think this is a bottleneck in your code? Did you build your code with optimizations and profile your execution and found out that casting from floats to ints takes the biggest share of time?

Comment: sorry mistake it's 'long' and not 'inline'.

Comment: maybe you got misled by `floor` from `cmath` being actually useful. The reason is that it returns a `float`. If it would return an integer, I have no clue what would it be good for in c++, you dont need `floor` (or some other fancy stuff) to convert a `float` to an `int`

Comment: I just want to know if this is faster than floor() because i'm working on large data that i convert from float to int. I use float instead of double to save memory.

Comment: you dont need `floor` to convert a `float` to an `int` in the first place, so why do you care about being faster than `floor` ? There is some misunderstanding, I am just not sure what it is exactly

Comment: @Random why not just cast the `float`/`double` directly to an `int`/`long` or have it implicitly converted? That'll be the fastest.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman [MSVC reports a warning](https://godbolt.org/z/q9eYzbsxY), clang does so with `-Weverything` only. But it would make sense to warn about that really.

Comment: @OP Do you need particular rounding behavior?  You mention `floor()` which always rounds toward negative infinity.  Many of the alternatives round toward zero.  Is this important?

Comment: @OP: Can you guarantee that a `long` is sufficient to hold the rounded `float`?

Comment: @BenVoigt Toward  zero.

Comment: @Random: Ah, then you didn't want `floor()` in the first place.  Please edit your question to mention the desired rounding behavior.

Comment: BTW, this is probably the undefined behavior Eljay was talking about, but your `* (unsigned int*) &x` looks like a violation of strict aliasing.

Comment: 30 years ago, pre-SIMD, you could get fast conversion to integer assuming the value was between 0.0f and 8388607.0f (specifically not negative, and not too big, and not NAN, and not ±Infinity), and IEEE 754, by adding 8388608.0f and masking to just the 0x7FFFFF bits (these days really requires a memcpy of the float to an int, then masking; a union or big hammer cast would be undefined behavior).  Paint Shop Pro used that technique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets compare the following two:

```
long ftoint(float x)
{
    unsigned int e = (0x7F + 31) - ((* (unsigned int*) &x & 0x7F800000) >> 23);
    unsigned int m = 0x80000000 | (* (unsigned int*) &x << 8);
    return int((m >> e) & -(e < 32));
}

long ftointfast(float x){ return x; }
```

Clang with -O3 produces:

```
ftoint(float):                             # @ftoint(float)
        movd    eax, xmm0
        mov     ecx, eax
        shr     ecx, 23
        movzx   edx, cl
        mov     ecx, 158
        sub     ecx, edx
        shl     eax, 8
        or      eax, -2147483648
        shr     eax, cl
        xor     edx, edx
        cmp     ecx, 32
        cmovb   edx, eax
        movsxd  rax, edx
        ret
ftointfast(float):                        # @ftointfast(float)
        cvttss2si       rax, xmm0
        ret
```

I am not fluent in assembly, but I am certain that you cannot get it faster than a single instruction.

`std::floor(arg)` [computes the largest integer value not greater than arg](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor). It returns a floating point value. If you do not need a floating point value but only the integer then you do not need `std::floor`. You also do not need to compare your solution to `std::floor` because it does something you don't need. And of course you can just write (assuming `x` actually fits in the range of `long`):

```
long y = x;
```

or to be explicit

```
long y = static_cast<long>(x);
```

Comment: it's much more tricky than that and a single instruction can be slower than a bunch of instruction. And it depend on the target cpu and the allowed instruction set. This topic is a school case of "don't try to outsmart your compiler"  :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably with

```
long ftoint(float x)
{
    return (long)x;
}
```

(or `static_cast` if you hate C-style casts)

In fact, you don't need a function. You can just write the cast.

Comment: This has "round-toward-zero" behavior, "floor" has round-down behavior.  Not the same.

Comment: However, the question doesn't say it needs to round down.

Comment: i went with static_cast<int>(var_b);